# Drivers para conexão com banco via ASP Clássico

Tags: sql-server, asp, conexão

Boa tarde.
Na connection string de nossa aplicação web, sempre utilizamos o Driver {SQL Server}.
Temos outras opções como por exemplo {SQL Server Native Client 11.0}.
Quais os critérios de tomada de decisão para escolher um ou outro?
Tem algum artigo que explique cada tipo?

Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve ainda considerar a sua escolha de drivers baseada em outros fatores como:

- este driver é confiável e foi bem testado?
- este driver é compatível com minha infraestrutura e arquitetura?
- este driver oferece os recursos que minha aplicação precisa?
- este driver tem algum problema de licença?
- este driver tem a melhor performance disponível

Geralmente, ao escolher entre um driver OLEDB e um driver ODBC, prefiro o driver OLE por ser mais performático e confiável

Mais informações aqui: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSc78c5058ca073340dcda9110b1f693f21-7a11a.html

http://serolmar.wordpress.com/2008/03/05/ligacao-a-bases-de-dados-odbc-e-ole-db-e-ado/

Answer (score 0):

Bom, quanto mais novo o driver, mais versões do SQL Server sua aplicação terá compatibilidade. Acho que é esta a lógica. O Native Client é o driver com o maior espectro de compatibidade dentre todos os outros.

Em se tratando de desempenho, a diferença é desprezível.

Há dois links que podem ser interessantes, com exemplos de conexões para cada cenário de aplicação, e com recomendações de uso do Native Client em comparação com outros drivers disponíveis:

> http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/
>   http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-native-client-use/